# cheack if url works in android

Tags: java, android, webview

I am implementing web view and parsing URLs to it from other activities, I want to know how to check if the phone had the internet not just connected, sometimes I am connected to wifi but there is no internet and also is the URL. I don't want to show the default NO internet page. I want to implement my own one[image]

I used this code:

```
 void chkStatus() {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting ()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting ()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above Android 6, you can use NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET to identify if the device network is validated or not.

[official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities)

> Indicates that connectivity on this network was successfully validated.
> For example, for a network with NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET, it means that Internet connectivity was successfully detected.

```
NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
Log.i("Avalible","NetworkCapalbilities:"+networkCapabilities.toString());
return networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
```